# How to make linked hash map navigable?

Tags: java, linkedhashmap

I have a `LinkedHashMap` with the `UUID` keys and instance of my custom class as the value. Order of these entries must be the same as the inserting order.
I need to process entries, and during processing I want to know, is I process the last entry, or not, and I want to move to previous or next entity.
Looks like I need a hybrid between `NavigableMap` (navigation function) and `LinkedHashMap` (save inserting order).

How can I resolve this, what is the best way? If the `LinkedHashMap` elements are linked, why can't I move beetwen it?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Its really important to ask questions properly here. Have a look at [ask] and [mcve]. Thanks

Comment: Can you show an example to demonstrate the use case and some code too

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://thebiasplanet.blogspot.com/2017/11/letscreateanavigableandelements-insertablelinkedhashmap.html You can google more solutions probably

Comment: This is a Use Case - I have a list of task, in order user was wrote. This task present a process. I need to execute this process. In normal case it knows I must execute every task in initial order. But after task executing I need to handle it, and every task can 
transfer control to the other task - next, previous, or any other. And I need to know what is task number in order, maybe it is the last task, and I need to finish process handling?

Answer (score 1):

[ListOrderedMap](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections4/map/ListOrderedMap.html) from Apache commons offers the functionality you describe. E.g.

```
ListOrderedMap<String, String> data = new ListOrderedMap<>();
data.put("2", "b");
data.put("1", "a");
data.put("5", "c");
System.out.println(data.firstKey());
System.out.println(data.lastKey());
System.out.println(data.get(1));
System.out.println(data.get("2"));
```

Note that there are `get` methods by int (insertion order) and by key and both are O(1) as it's backed by a `HashMap` and an `ArrayList`

Comment: Wow, thanks, I'll try this. But is the code example correct? You talking about of ListOrderedMap, but there is an LinkedMap in example.

Comment: It wasn't but it is now ;-) `LinkedMap` uses a `LinkedList` instead of an `ArrayList` which makes searching slower but inserting/deleting faster.

Comment: I think it will really help me. Thank you!